# Adding a space after the first character

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have string like this

```
8prob566459
```

Required output :

```
8 prob566459
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: have a look at [extracting sub-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/502/shell-parameter-expansion/1654/substrings-and-subarrays#t=201610200544333887858)

Answer (score 3):

If you need that to be applied to each line of a file:

```
sed 's/./& /' < file
```

For it to be applied to a string stored in a shell variable:

```
string=8prob566459
printf '%s\n' "${string%"${string#?}"} ${string#?}"
```

Though you could always also do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed '1s/./& /'
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$string[1] $string[2,-1]"
```

Or:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
printf '%s\n' ${string/(#m)?/$MATCH }
```

Or with `ksh93`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${string/?/\0 }"
```

Or with `zsh`, `ksh93` or `bash`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${string:0:1} ${string:1}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "$(echo 8prob566459 | cut -c 1 ) $(echo 8prob566459 | cut -c 2- )"
```

this will work